# Is 1 g/l living biomass for a Biogas fermenter plausible?

Tags: bacteriology, biotechnology, fermentation

A usual number for a healthy biogas fermenter is $10^9 - 10^{10}/mL$ Bacteria, 10-15% of which would be methanogenic archae. Exceptionally healthy fermenters have more total bacteria and up 25% archae.

The mass of *E. coli* is given with 670 femtograms. If *E. coli* is representative for fermenting bacteria that would put us on the order of magnitude of 1 g/L living biomass.

This seems like much to me, though this is just a gut feeling. 
As additional information, such a fermenter will have a total solids content of about 10%. A typical loading rate will be 4-5 g VS/d l *, two thirds of which get metabolized to gas. To put it another way: The amount of digested biomass per day would be the same order of magnitude as the living biomass. However, as anaerobic digestion is a multistage process, with at least three steps, each population will have a higher rate of digestion to mass.

Are the numbers basically sound? Is *E. coli* an exceptional bacterium in terms of mass? Are archae generally as massive as bacteria? What are bacteria counts for other fermentation processes?

(*) g volatile solid per day and liter: for each liter fermenter volume, this many g potentially degradable matter are added per day

Comment: Not sure if the tag 'digestive system' is really appropriate.

Comment: could you write out some of your abbreviations?  a bioengineer might not be here to answer your question, but someone will probably find it for you if someone not from the field could read it.  Also I expect that there is a huge variation in this behavior for archaea.  you want to make a methanogenic fermentor and are looking for an upper limit, yes? this might help...http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723202008000222

Comment: I think the only possivle abbreviation was VS, did I miss any other?

Comment: VS yes; VS/d volatile solids is days- ok. TS, AD?

Comment: Fecal matter can contain up to 10^12 microbial cells/gram. The colon is essentially an incredibly efficient biogas fermenter. So your numbers seem plausible to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've done experiments with yeast, and they can easily ferment glucose at the rate of 4g/L/d.  Probably faster, if one were to optimize it.  So your numbers don't seem crazy.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that?